# Why is it possible for interfaces to contain classes in VB .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have written an interface definition in a VB .NET 2010 project. To my surprise, I discovered that fully-fledged classes can be defined within interface definitions. A simple example:

```
Friend Interface IProcessor

    Class InvalidDataException
        Inherits System.Exception

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("Invalid data.")
        End Sub

    End Class

    ReadOnly Property State As System.String
    Sub Process(data As System.Byte())

End Interface
```

I have found a use for the functionality: to define custom exception classes with the interface itself rather than outside of it. This seems to make sense because the custom exceptions are relevant specifically to the classes that will implement the interface.

My question is two-fold:

1. Why is this possible – I always thought interfaces could not contain implementation?
2. Am I going to get myself into unforeseen trouble doing this?

If it’s one of those subjective things, so be it – I’ll make a call :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this possible – I always thought interfaces could not contain implementation?

Nesting classes and interfaces in .NET is just a means of organization that you should use when appropriate; the classes and instances themselves aren’t instantiated together or even related that much beyond namespacing.

Think of it like a `Shared` field or constant; put it there if it makes sense for it to go there.

> Am I going to get myself into unforeseen trouble doing this?

Unforeseen? Almost definitely not. Some people could find it slightly confusing, but yes, that’s subjective. It’s not going to behave any differently than a nested class or a class in a namespace.